# Get user account content object loaded in node.tpl.php

Tags: theming, users, 6

By default `$account->content` object is loaded only on user page.

I want to print `$account->content` in node.tpl.php.

In `user-profile.tpl.php`, I tried echo `"<pre>"; print_r($account);` and `$account->content` is fully loaded.

How would I do the the same in `node.tpl.php` ? I tried with `user_load(1);` but `account->content` is not built.

Comment: You several times change the question,please before you ask a question think about what you want , really you waste another guys time with changing the question , :(

Comment: **My question is being put on hold, Reason Please check below answer and comments

Hey all developers on this druapl.stackexchange, I want your help for keeping up this question on stackexange. 

You can do this by voting my question**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly build the account content since it is not done automatically outside the context of *user_view* operation. I would do it this way :

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function yourmodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  global $user;
  $account = user_load($user->uid);
  user_build_content($account); 
  $variables['account'] = $account;
}
```

Then, just print `$account->content` in *node.tpl.php*.

The key is to call `user_build_content($account)` where `$account` is passed by reference, it also returns the fully-built account content (more commonly known as profile).

Comment: nice way, vote up

Comment: @n0tting your code solution looks workable, but noidea it was not working for me through module partially, i had used your code solution  it had worked for me in the below way using in **node.tpl.php**  


`global $user;
$accountload = user_load($user->uid);
$account = user_build_content($accountload); 
echo "<pre>"; print_r($account);`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);
```

Comment: I have checked `account->content` object is not loaded,

Comment: @Rishi  tell me exactly what you want? uid? username? what you want?

Comment: @zhileavn want to get `account->content` object in node.tpl.php

Comment: Try echo `"<pre>"; print_r($account);` in `user-profile.tpl.php` It will load `$account->content` object,  When the same is done in `node.tpl.php` `$account->content` object is not shown, how to get it

Comment: Not all variables are available in tpl files, for sure when you are theming user-profile, $account must be available but not when theming a node, now if you want to add the account of visitor to node.tpl.php you can use same code @zhilevan has suggested, if you want author's account then use $account = user_load(node->uid);

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add account of site visitor use this code in the beginning of your tpl file :

```
<?php
  global $user;
  $account = user_load($user->uid);
?>
```

else if you want to add account of node author, then try this:

```
<?php
  $account = user_load($node->uid);
?>
```

the reason is that in node tpl files drupal does not provide user information by default.

Comment: The question was unclear, he several times change it, once asked how to get user info, once asked node author , .....